# CSS :has(+) for previous sibling elements

Tags: css

So I just read that I can target [previous sibling elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) with the `:has(+ )` pseudo-class.

I went and did implement the following rule. Unfortunately, this is not working. Am I wissing somethin?

```css
p {
  margin: 2rem;
}

p:has(a[class*="link--button"]):has( + p:has(a[class*="link--button"])) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <a class="link--button" href="#">first link</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a class="link--button" href="#">second link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

You may also find the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/au4zegx5/1/#&togetherjs=vODb7CBEoH)

Here is also another article [The CSS :has() selector is way more than a “Parent Selector](https://www.bram.us/2021/12/21/the-css-has-selector-is-way-more-than-a-parent-selector/) mentioning it

Comment: You mean `p:has(a[class*="link--button"]) + p:has(a[class*="link--button"])` ?

Comment: No. Like that you will target the next sibling. I want the previous. In my case, this would be the first link. So I want the `margin-bottom: 0` to apply to the first link element.

Comment: Note that `:has()` is [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

Comment: Yeah, my advice would be to add an class, since the support of `has()` isn't very good.

Comment: @LinkinTED Unfortunately, I can not control the HTML and class names. This is just being delivered like this from a CMS.

Comment: Could you explain what you actually want to do, without suggesting a solution, as I’m not clear.

Comment: @AHaworth In a series of `<p><a></a></p>` elements inside a `div`, I want to target all elements besides the last one and apply a `margin-bottom: 0`. I could also probably do it by applying it to all `margin-bottom: 0` and then try to target the last element and apply the needed `margin-bottom`

Comment: I fyou want to target all elements beside the last one have you tried :not ?

Comment: @AHaworth How? I have tried somethin similar to this `p:has(a[class*="link--button"]):not(:last-child)` with no luck.

Comment: @AHaworth Upsie. I think my last comment is working :) Still, this does not answer the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `:has()` pseudo-class cannot be nested;](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#relational)

However. I think `p:has(a[class*="link--button"]):has(+ p a[class*="link--button"])` meets what you're trying to do.

Note that using `margin-bottom` results in an unclear test, because the bottom margin of the first p element will collapse with the top margin of the second p element anyway.

So I've added a color declaration to show that the selector is working.

```css
p {
  margin: 2rem;
  color:red;
}

p:has(a[class*="link--button"]):has(+ p a[class*="link--button"]) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color:green;
}
a {
  color:inherit
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <a class="link--button" href="#">first link</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a class="link--button" href="#">second link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: When I run the code they're still both red :(

Comment: @caTS - which browser and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 96.0.4664.219, but if it's because of the browser, I understand. I'll check if this version supports :has first.